# Odd output from dsmc (Tivoli storage manager or TSM) query backup

Tags: ubuntu, backup, restore

I'm using TSM (dsmc) on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
# dsmc
IBM Spectrum Protect
Befehlszeilenschnittstelle des Clients für Sichern/Archivieren
  Clientversion 8, Release 1, Stufe 8.0 
  Client-Datum/Zeit: 04.12.2019 13:57:40
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s) 1990, 2019.
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation und Andere 1990, 2019. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Knotenname: ServernameB
Sitzung hergestellt mit Server SB05: AIX
  Serverversion 7, Release 1, Stufe 7.300
  Serverdatum/-zeit: 04.12.2019 13:57:41  Letzter Zugriff: 04.12.2019 13:47:43
```

When I try to run a `dsmc query backup` command, I'm getting vers unusual results.

I'm using [this](https://help.it.ox.ac.uk/hfs/help/dsmc) as a reference.

When I try to see the contents of `"/common/share/archive"` it seems to reply with `"/common/share/*/archive"`.

**All of the responses returned are ONLY for files named "archive", that live anywhere below "/common/share/"**

I.e.Trying ...

```
q ba /common/share/archive/ -subdir=yes
```

...or...

```
q ba /common/share/archive/* -subdir=yes
```

...both return nothing.

**Output:**

```
Protect> q ba /common/share/archive -subdir=yes
            Größe     Sicher.-Datum              Verw.klasse           A/I Datei
            -----     -------------              -----------           --- -----
            10  B  27.05.2019 11:57:10             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/LibrarySources/Qt-4.6.3/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            10  B  27.05.2019 12:02:14             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/LibrarySources/Qt-4.7.2/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:03:51             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/LibrarySources/boost_1_44_0/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:06:53             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/LibrarySources/boost_1_46_1/boost/archive
            11  B  27.05.2019 12:17:54             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/Qt/build/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.3/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            10  B  27.05.2019 12:23:27             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/Qt/build/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.1/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:31:32             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.38.0/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:31:55             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.38.0/boost_install/include/boost-1_38/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:34:46             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.42.0/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:35:09             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.42.0/boost_install/include/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:37:29             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.44.0/include/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:38:36             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.44.0_withInstalledLibraries/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:39:23             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.44.0_withInstalledLibraries/boost_install/include/boost/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 12:42:54             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.48/include/boost/archive
            52  B  27.05.2019 12:44:09             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.54.0/boost_1_54_0/boost/archive
            52  B  27.05.2019 12:46:18             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/1.54.0/include/boost/archive
            52  B  27.05.2019 12:46:55             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/boost/old2_1.44.0/include/boost/archive
             4  B  27.05.2019 13:09:07             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/old/simox/simox_current_version_sourceforge/build_10.04/VirtualRobot/CMakeFiles/Export/_org/share/archive
             4  B  27.05.2019 13:09:21             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/old/simox/simox_current_version_sourceforge/build_8.04/VirtualRobot/CMakeFiles/Export/_org/share/archive
            53  B  27.05.2019 13:13:02             STANDARD             A  /common/share/Armar3/SFB588_RefDist/x86_64/boost/include/boost/archive
            10  B  27.07.2019 13:41:36             STANDARD             A  /common/share/backup/i61pc011/sda2/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/statsmodels/sandbox/archive
             7  B  27.07.2019 15:39:43             STANDARD             A  /common/share/backup/i61pc011/sda2/libs/Qt/4.6.1-x64/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            10  B  27.07.2019 15:40:56             STANDARD             A  /common/share/backup/i61pc011/sda2/libs/Qt/4.6.2/qt/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            10  B  27.07.2019 15:44:00             STANDARD             A  /common/share/backup/i61pc011/sda2/libs/x64/Qt/4.6.2/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebCore/loader/archive
            52  B  27.07.2019 15:47:33             STANDARD             A  /common/share/backup/i61pc011/sda2/libs/x64/boost144/boost/archive
             7  B  18.07.2019 03:39:03             STANDARD             A  /common/share/project/HIS PROJEKTE ausgelaufen/10. Dissemination/Organisierte_Konferenzen-Workshops/stattgefunden/ECMR-2007/ECMR2007_homepage/archive
Protect>
```

Comment: Is `archive` a symlink, by chance?

Comment: Not a simlink, but it is a ZFS sub-datastore. I.e. `zfs list` shows both `zpool/share                  12,1T  7,72T  10,2T  /common/share
` and `zpool/share/archive          1,82T  7,72T  1,82T  /common/share/archive`